# File upload cancel using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I'm trying to upload multiple files using angular `ng-fileupload`, as well as `cancel` event in order to stop the uploaded files, or server request to the uploading file.

I have a user abort event, the server request gets canceled, but the file get uploaded to the server and the values are updated in the database.

How could I stop the file upload after clicking the `submit` event (the file should not be uploaded to the server).

Any ideas, please?

Comment: How can anybody help you given the information at hand? Please click **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44679771/edit)** 
your question and make sure you have a valid **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, 
else, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: No, you can not cancel an existing upload using front-end code alone. It will need to be implemented in the back-end that can roll-back the data with a API call that the front-end makes.